# Why is the calculus of constructions called that way, and what is a "construction" in CoC?

Tags: logic, foundations, formal-proofs, constructive-mathematics, type-theory

I'm reading about the calculus of construction Nederpelt & Geuvers' book "Type theory and formal proof".

I can see that CoC allows us to extend the curry howard isomorphism from simply typed lambda calculus to full predicate logic. **I can see how CoC allows one to do higher order logic in type theory.**

But when I think of a "construction", I think of a **mathematical**, not **logical** notion, namely the informal idea of "constructing an object from other objects" (e.g. constructing the real numbers from the rationals, or constructing a product topological space from two topological spaces).

**Is this latter concept of "construction" actually what the "calculus of constructions" refers to? Is this why it is called that way?** I would find this surprising (but interesting), given that CoC by Nederpelt & Geuvers is being presented primarily as a tool to do predicate logic in.

Also, they present a "construction" as a term of e.g. type $*\to *$ (or $Type\to Type$. i.e. it takes a type to a type). But it seems to me that the two examples given above are not examples of this: e.g. the construction of the reals cannot be performed on an arbitrary type, it can only be performed on the rational numbers.

Comment: I've always thought "construction" refers to [type constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_constructor)

Comment: @wojowu, can we use type constructors to formalize "constructions" in the mathematical sense? This would clarify to me somewhat, why CoC can be used as a foundation for constructive mathematics (see the wikipedia page)

Comment: See page 85 : a *constructor* is a function with a type as value.

Comment: The example with numbers can be similar; we have objects of a certain "category" : natural numbers, and we build a new "category" of objects : the integers, as a pair of naturals.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, but what if your construction depends on specific properties of the natural numbers? Then we can't have the construction be of type $*\to *$ right?

Comment: But it seems that the [Calculus of constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions#The_basics_of_the_calculus_of_constructions) has been named so for its link with the full intuitionistic predicate calculus, that is a *constructive* logic.